# I can't see the Other Demos for Google Calendar on fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I open http://fullcalendar.io/ see the Other Demos for Google Calendar,but I can't see the event on the Google Calendar
I try to check the orign html code and find the http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic to link,it is the event on the Google Calendar but not show

Answer (score 0):

Google API shutdown that affected FullCalendar
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/